# Connecting Django web application to python class library

Tags: python, django

I have a Django web application that runs couple of apps, I want this Django application to connect with the  the other python project [which is not a web application] that has it's own data base.

What I am trying to achieve is, when a user inputs a keyword and clicks search button in the django application the call has to go to the python project and execute the functionalities that it offers and display the results in the django application web page.

If someone can explain me on how to achieve this that would be great.

Comment: You need to decide on how two apps will communicate. In order to do so you should see if they will run on the same machine or not. For example if you choose socket, non web app should listen and web app should connect to it via that protocol.

Comment: I am planning to run them on the same machine. Is it possible to have these class library files inside of django application and run it?

Comment: What do you mean by class library? If it is Python lib you can import and use it in any Python project.

Comment: It's a set of 4 python files and a common database for these 4 files..

Comment: Guess you can integrate those files into your own project.

Comment: the python project that I have returns pandas data set as an output, but Django works on HTTP. Any idea how to integrate them

Comment: Merging two software projects is possible but the methods and approach used depends on the goals in mind and qualities of the projects. Please ask a more specific question.